# Replace email adress by string name in a dataframe

Tags: r, replace, tidyverse

I have a dataframe containing a list of observers ($Observer.names) but some are email addresses. I want to replace the observer's email by the string "Anonymous birder". Can anyone help?

```
 glimpse(data)

Rows: 2,706
Columns: 6
$ Observer.names <chr> NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Allan Mueller", "Allan Mue...
$ Date           <chr> "5/27/2019", "5/27/2019", "5/27/2019", "6/15/2019", "6/15/2019", "6...
$ Start.time     <chr> "8:14:00", "8:25:00", "8:54:00", "16:40:00", "18:11:00", "7:09:00",...
$ latitude       <dbl> 34.05200, 34.04500, 34.00300, 40.12670, 40.13630, 42.10672, 42.1044...
$ longitude      <dbl> -84.34200, -84.33800, -84.30000, -75.60830, -75.59200, -93.57307, -...
$ AMGO           <int> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0...
```

This is what tried but it only returns a vector:

```
    a <- data %>% 
        select(Observer.names) %>% 
        replace_email(replacement = "Anonymous Birder")
```

Comment: Instead of glimpse, you should use `dput(data)` or `dput(head(data))` to share your data. This lets people easily copy/paste it.

Comment: Make sure to list all non-base R packages you are using. Where does `replace_email` come from?

Comment: Do you need anything fancy? `replace(Observer.names, grepl("@", Observer.Names), "anon")`?

Comment: Please share more data from your Observer.name variable, i.e. a sample entry that you would want to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add a new column with emails replaced:

```
data$Observer.names.replaced <- replace_email(data$Observer.names, replacement="Anonymous Birder")
```

I assumed that `replace_email` function comes from `textclean` package

Comment: Yes replace_email is from the package textclean. Do you know how I can retain all the column within my dataframe when I change the emails?

Comment: I am not sure if I get you right, but of course all the original columns remain unchanged, the code above just adds a new column into your dataframe.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for your help!